# Excel VBA read pivot table and display msgbox

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table and the following VBA which displays a msgbox for the first row field, but I need it to go through all row fields displaying a message box for each one, can someone point me in the right direction, I cant seem to work out how to do it

```
Sub Piv()

  Dim PvTable As PivotTable
  Dim PvField As PivotField
  Dim PvItem As PivotItem

  Set PvTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RawDataTable")
  Set PvField = PvTable.RowFields(1)

  With ws
    For Each PvItem In PvField.PivotItems
      MsgBox PvItem

    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

I can also get it to give me all the field headers, but not the data

```
Sub Piv()

  Dim PvTable As PivotTable
  Dim PvField As PivotField
  Dim PvItem As PivotItem

  Set PvTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RawDataTable")

  With ws
    For Each PvField In PvTable.PivotFields
      MsgBox PvField

    Next
  End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but in the first example, can't you wrap your `For` loop in another `For` loop: `For Each PvField In PvTable.RowFields`

Comment: That works but its looping the wrong way, it gives me all of the first columns data then the second column and so forth, but I want to go across the whole row then move to the next

Comment: Out of curiosity,  what is the intention of these messageboxes? What do you need the user to do after each one displays?  And will you give the user a way to  exit out of the procedure half way through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly brute-force approach, and hopefully someone will come up with something more elegant, but we can read the details of the row fields into an array of arrays, and then run through this array in reverse index order:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Piv()

    Dim PvTable As PivotTable
    Dim PvField As PivotField
    Dim PvItem As PivotItem
    Dim dataArray() As Variant
    Dim dummyArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Set PvTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RawDataTable")

    ReDim dataArray(1 To PvTable.RowFields.Count)
    ReDim dummyArray(1 To PvTable.RowFields(1).PivotItems.Count)

    For i = 1 To PvTable.RowFields.Count
        dataArray(i) = dummyArray
        For j = 1 To PvTable.RowFields(i).PivotItems.Count
            dataArray(i)(j) = PvTable.RowFields(i).PivotItems(j)
        Next j
    Next i

    For i = 1 To UBound(dataArray(1))
        For j = 1 To UBound(dataArray)
            MsgBox dataArray(j)(i)
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```